# Can one get the list of following blogs from blogger api or gdata api?

Tags: android, json, blogger

I have been looking for a solution, but the only format that I can get a response to the profile API is in HTML.  That is not very reliable for getting something like a list of the blogger's reading list.

I have been able to get the default/blogs with my auth token and have the result returned in JSON.  I then used that to get the author's blog-id .. and then .. the profile (which has the reading list).  Howver, when I request it in JSON (i.e., ?v=2/alt=json) at the end of the URI, it still returns HTML.

Is there a better way to get this done?

Comment: Can someone close this as a duplicate of my other question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465149/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-followers-from-the-google-data-api-for-blogger

Answer (score 1):

No - not really (keep reading).  Yes if you parse HTML.  It is not exposed in the API for XML/JSON or otherwise.  You can get the HTML and if you are confident in doing the screen scraping and feel that the owner will not rearrange one's page (possibly omitting it from display), then 'go for it.'