# How can I get the list of followers from the Google Data API for Blogger?

Tags: xml, json, gdata-api, blogger

I am able to get the list of 'authored' blogs for a particular user profile-id and its response is available in JSON.  However, when I try to request the profile (which has the list of followers), I can only get the result in HTML.

Is there any way to get the list in a data-protocol format (i.e., XML or JSON)?

Comment: Sorry -- I think I am spamming with two of the same questions (I have lost my mind)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459247/can-one-get-the-list-of-following-blogs-from-blogger-api-or-gdata-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several days trying different APIs, I am convinced that the list of followers is not available through Blogger.  I worked with the Blogger API, the Client Libraries and built the GData java client from source to use the Containers and BloggerService classes.  Each one, provided access to the feeds (as expected) in a programmable-protocol fashion and the profile, which displays the list of following blogs (not to be confused with the authored blogs) -- can only be returned as HTML.  This is not practical for a programming interface as the user can choose to not show the widget.  Why isn't this available??  I think it is one of three reasons:

1. Simply omitted from the API as not essential.
2. Intentionally blocked for business reasons.
3. Work in progress (i.e., it will be available in a future release)

It is possible that the information is available through and for Google Friends Connect.  I have been reading some of that material (following Leniel's suggestion above).  However, I am curious how that will try back the relationship to Blogger -- if at all.

Anyway, the task is dead for now.  Thanks for listening!